# 2 UIButtons which are resized according to inner text and have equal width simultaneously?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, constraints, interface-builder

On my screen I have 2 buttons like on this picture (but without titles):
 [image: dra]

I used constraints. Left button is binded to the left side, right - to the right side. How to make them simultaneously:

1. of equal width;
2. resized according to inner text?

The better case I can achieve without of manual size calculations is they are of equal width but resized according to inner text of the smallest button.

Comment: How can you simultaneously satisfy both the constraint even logically? You wanna have equal width but want to resize the button according to text as well

Comment: If they would be 2 similar constraints with different priorities then iOS by default tried to satisfy both of them first! If it wasn't not possible then constraint with lower priority was ignored. So it is normal situation.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov - do you want each button to keep the spacing to the sides of the view, but adjust the spacing between them based on the button titles? So you might have (for example): `|_[b1]_______________[b2]_|` or `|_[button 1]___[___b2___]_|` ? This image is a little easier to understand: https://imgur.com/a/Jr7B56A

Comment: @DonMag yes, you understood me correctly. Currently I have implemented this with manual size calculation + they requested to adjust font size if button1 and button2 have too long title and so adjusted buttons may overlap each other but shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

1.Use two button inside stackView and Distribute it FillEqually with the spacing you required and with the stackview constraint leading trailing with the superview.

2.Use two button inside stackView and Distribute it FillProportionally with the spacing you required and with the stackview constraint leading trailing with the superview.

you can Distribute it by comparing the length of the titles too

Comment: Did you tried it by yourself? In both cases you suggest to use a fixed spacing which has influence on buttons' width. Instead of calculating button width you suggest to calculate a spacing between buttons which is even harder and worse!

Comment: i said just add the leading and trailing constraint of the stackView to the superView and calculate the length of the title of both the buttons if they are not equal then distribute it FillProportional else distribute it FillEqually and dont think fixed spacing will effect the way stackView distribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, with a caveat...

- Constrain the Left Button's `Leading` to the view's `Leading` (plus the desired padding)
- Constrain the Right Button's `Trailing` to the view's `Trailing` (plus the desired padding)
- Ctrl-Drag from Left Button to Right Button and select `Equal Widths`
- Set vertical constraints as desired (top to above element, bottom to bottom of view, however it works for your vertical positioning).

[image]

Now, the Left Button's left edge will stay at 16-pts from the left edge of the view... the Right Button's right edge will stay at 16-pts from the right edge of the view... and the buttons will size to fit the longer title.

For the caveat -- If your button titles are too long, the buttons will overlap:

[image]

If you ***know*** your titles will never cause that, you don't need to worry. However, to prevent the overlap, you can add a Left Button Trailing to Right Button Leading constraint of `>= 16` (or however much spacing you want):

[image]

That *will* cause the button title to be truncated (`...`), but that's probably better than the overlap.

Here's the source for this Storyboard, in case you have any trouble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="iN1-OP-drt">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Ele-XE-2pT" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="aqv-SZ-ggJ">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Upr-w7-EFK" userLabel="LeftButton">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="621" width="163.5" height="30"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.4756349325" green="0.47564673419999998" blue="0.47564041610000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Left Button">
                                    <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                </state>
                            </button>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="uSP-G0-fwa" userLabel="RightButton">
                                <rect key="frame" x="195.5" y="621" width="163.5" height="30"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.58980089430000004" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Really Long Title for Right Button">
                                    <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                </state>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="uSP-G0-fwa" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Upr-w7-EFK" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="FBv-nj-wdy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="frC-yx-t9o" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="uSP-G0-fwa" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="ait-JI-b7g"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="frC-yx-t9o" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="uSP-G0-fwa" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="fQT-AE-SiC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="frC-yx-t9o" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Upr-w7-EFK" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="nTH-Jg-7Cz"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Upr-w7-EFK" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="frC-yx-t9o" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="xEW-CH-yaZ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Upr-w7-EFK" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="uSP-G0-fwa" secondAttribute="width" id="zl6-e8-hRM"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="frC-yx-t9o"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="gZ2-hX-7aO" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-1339" y="615"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: there is something wrong with your answer. The first picture - if you disable "equal width" constraint then buttons have different width but equal insets. On your first picture the right button has side insets `~0px` which means the app calculated the left button's size and applied it to the right one independently from its text.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov - the buttons do not have insets defined. The OP stated he wants the buttons to be equal widths, based on the (longer) button title. That means the button with the shorter title *will* have extra space... you can't have two different title lengths with the same size buttons any other way. With the constraints set as I have them, that's exactly the result.